# I get error 400 when sending data to my API on flutter

Tags: api, flutter

when trying to send data to my Api i get error 400 with the following message :

```
{"errors":{"email":["Enter a valid email address."]}}
```

But when I introduce the same data manually directly on the API it works fine, what problem could I have?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please post your code

Comment: the code: https://github.com/guillemrh/urbix/blob/master/lib/screens/signup_screen_administrador.dart

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code. A 400 error means a bad request error - so what are the values that your Api expects ?